# Alinhar Popup ao Centro

Tags: c#, windows-phone, popup, xaml

Por que eu não consigo alinhar ao centro, esse meu popup?

[image: Popup]

Olha como ele fica no Design do XAML

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu `XAML`:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Background="Black" Width="456">
        <TextBlock Text="Selecione uma ação:" Name="lblInformaPopup" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Name="imgPhone" Source="Assets/Images/telefone.png" Width="70" Height="70" Tap="imgPhone_Tap" />
            <Image Name="imgGps" Source="Assets/Images/gps.png" Width="70" Height="70" Tap="imgGps_Tap" Margin="15,0,0,0"  />
            <Image Name="imgEmail" Source="Assets/Images/email.png" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="15,0,0,0"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

**Sugestões?**

Comment: Boa tarde, veja se este exemplo te ajuda: `var p = new Popup();
var content = new TextBox { Text = "hello world!" };
p.Child = content;
p.VerticalOffset = (this.ActualHeight - content.ActualHeight) / 2;
p.HorizontalOffset = (this.ActualWidth - content.ActualWidth) / 2;
p.IsOpen = true;`

Comment: o que é esse `content` ? @cavalsilva. Por que ta falando que ele não existe: **The name 'content' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve definir as dimensões da tag `Popup` para poder centralizá-la.

Por exemplo:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="456" Height="70">
    <StackPanel Background="Black" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Selecione uma ação:" Name="lblInformaPopup" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Name="imgPhone" Source="Assets/Images/telefone.png" Width="70" Height="70" Tap="imgPhone_Tap" />
            <Image Name="imgGps" Source="Assets/Images/gps.png" Width="70" Height="70" Tap="imgGps_Tap" Margin="15,0,0,0"  />
            <Image Name="imgEmail" Source="Assets/Images/email.png" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="15,0,0,0"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Nesse caso, eu defini as dimensões para o `<Popup>` e o `<StackPanel>` herda as dimensões de `<Popup>` usando `Auto`.